# Laravel 5.1 : htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I'm encountering an error "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given", when I debug my code, this line from controller throwing the error.

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

*Controller*

```
  $rules = array(
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:inspector_details', // required and must be unique in the ducks table
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $messages = $validator->messages();
           return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
```

*VIEW*

```
       {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'inspector.store','class' => 'form','id' => 'createinspector','name' => 'createinspector','files' => true)) !!}
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="" />
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name<span class="redmark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" style="margin-bottom: 3px" value="{{ Input::old('firstname') }}" placeholder="Enter Name" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email<span class="redmark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ Input::old('email') }}" required="required">
                </div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="emailprivate" value="{{ Input::old('emailprivate') }}" id="emailprivate" style="margin-top: 3%">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-weight : 100" >Keep email private.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Zip Code<span class="redmark" id="zipvalidation" style="font-weight : 100;display: none">&emsp;Enter either 5 or 9 digits.</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" onkeydown="validateNumber(event);" maxlength="9" value="{{ Input::old('zip') }}" placeholder="Enter Zip Code">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Company<span class="redmark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" value="{{ Input::old('company') }}" placeholder="Enter Company Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Website</label>
                <input type="url" class="form-control" name="website" id="website" value="{{ Input::old('website') }}" placeholder="Enter Website url e.g http://www.google.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" onkeydown="validateNumber(event);" value="{{ Input::old('phone') }}" placeholder="Enter Phone number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Free text</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="freetext" id="freetext" value="{{ Input::old('freetext') }}" placeholder="Enter Text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">Select logo</label>
                {!! Form::file('logoimage', null) !!}
                <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.form-group -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Inspection Type</label>
                <select class="form-control select2" name="inspectiontype[]" id="inspectiontype" value="{{ Input::old('inspectiontype') }}" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Inspection Type" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value="home" selected="selected">home</option>
                    <option value="roof">roof</option>
                    <option value="asbestos">asbestos</option>
                    <option value="lead">lead</option>
                    <option value="HVAC">HVAC</option>
                    <option value="pest">pest</option>
                    <option value="septic">septic</option>
                    <option value="environmental">environmental</option>
                    <option value="plumbing">plumbing</option>
                    <option value="zoning">zoning</option>
                    <option value="mold">mold</option>
                    <option value="wood destroyin g organisms (WDO)">wood destroying organisms (WDO)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Company Begin Date:</label>
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" name="companybegindate" id="companybegindate" value="{{ Input::old('companybegindate') }}" id="datepicker">
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>street address 1<span class="redmark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="residaddress1" id="residaddress1" value="{{ Input::old('residaddress1') }}" placeholder="Enter Street Address 1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>street address 2<span class="redmark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="residaddress2" id="residaddress2" value="{{ Input::old('residaddress2') }}" placeholder="Enter Street Address 2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" value="{{ Input::old('city') }}" placeholder="Enter City">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>State<span class="redmark" id="statevalidation" style="font-weight : 100;display: none">&emsp;Enter two characters only e.g NJ</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="state" id="state" value="{{ Input::old('state') }}" placeholder="Enter State e.g NJ">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Licensing:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="licname" id="licname" value="{{ Input::old('licname') }}" style="margin-bottom: 2px" placeholder="Enter Licensing name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="licid" id="licid" style="margin-bottom: 2px" value="{{ Input::old('licid') }}" placeholder="Enter Licensing ID">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="licurl" id="licurl" style="margin-bottom: 2px" value="{{ Input::old('licurl') }}" placeholder="Enter URL to governing body">
            </div>
            <!-- /.form-group -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box-footer pull-left">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return validate_data()">Create Inspector</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Can you post the code you've used to make the validator?

Comment: Yes I posted..please check now.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you send only the email to the validator i.e. `$validator = Validator::make(Input::only('email'), $rules);` and specifying only part of the Input in `withInput()`?

Comment: Yes getting same error, I'm only validating email on server side. So only passing email to the validator.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is because you try to set input value as array.

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="inspectiontype[]" id="inspectiontype" value="{{ Input::old('inspectiontype') }}" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Inspection Type" style="width: 100%;">
```

Here you try set `array of ids` as value of select, but you need to add `selected` attribute to selected option.

```
{{ Input::old('inspectiontype') }}
```

transforms to

```
<?php echo htmlentities(array('id1', 'id2'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false)?>
```

I would recommend you to use [laravel collective form](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) it will do it for you