# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel

### I'm having a trouble regarding on this code. I'm writing a SQL query on the textarea part, submit it thru a button, then display the result set based on the user's input query. I'm just new to Laravel. Can someone help me on this? Below are my codes.

**This my Controller**

```
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
                    $query = $request->input("sql_query");
                    $submit = $request->input("execute_sql");

                    $fieldname= "";
                    $sqls = "";
                    $outputs = "";

                    if (isset($submit)) {

                        if ($query != "") {
                            $fieldname = str_replace("@name", "Tarpaulin", $query);


                            $outputs = "SELECT * FROM report_content WHERE field_name = 'Title'";

                            $sqls = DB::select(DB::raw($outputs));  

                        }

                    }

                    //die(); 

            return view('reports.create', compact('fieldtypes', 'json', 'query', 'submit'))
                            ->with('fieldname', $fieldname)
                            ->with('sqls', $sqls)
                            ->with('outputs', $outputs);
        }
```

**create.blade.php**

```
       <form id="sqlForm" action="{{ url('/reports/create') }}" method="GET">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('query')) has-error @endif">
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <textarea rows="7" cols="7" id="sql_query" name="sql_query" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="execute_sql" name="execute_sql"><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Filter</button>

                              </div>

                              <div class="col-md-5">      
                                  <table>
                                    @foreach($sqls as $sql)
                                    <tr id="field-default">
                                        <td>
                                        {{ $sql }}
                                        </td>  
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </table>  
                              </div>  
                            <div class="col-xs-5">

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">

                            </div>
                       </div>  
                      </div>
```

[Here's the result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42BvI.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755000/htmlentities-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given)

Comment: I can't see any call to `htmlentities()` in your code !

Comment: Accountantم what do you mean you can't see any call to htmlentities()?

Comment: @Jr.PHP where is the call you made to `htmlentities()` ?. your problem exists in that call which is not exist in the code you posted

Comment: Show the view please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It's under the controller section.

Comment: @Jr.PHP did you show whole view? If yes, then put this `{{ dd($sql) }}` before `{{ $sql }}` and paste somewhere the output please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I edited my question above. See the image at "Here's the result set".

Comment: Thanks. The problem is in `{{ $sql }}` - it's an object and you can't display it. You need to display properties of that object, for example: `{{ $sql->field_name }}`. If you want to output HTML ('content_source'), use `{!! $sql->content_source !!}` syntax instead.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I never down-voted a question on SO in my life :) because when people were down voting my questions and cause my old accounts to be blocked from asking, I was getting very sad. I'm just asking for the call to `htmlentities()`. but hey, we are lucky we have an expert in `Laravel/Blade` here, and that is the beauty of the SO

Comment: Down-voted for lack of effort on research.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin MAN IT WORKED!! Thanks a lot. I've been debugging this since yesterday for almost 3hours. It really helped me a lot. Thanks man!!

Comment: Hi guys, I'm really sorry for this type of question and I'm just a newbie in Laravel. I'm still coping with its environment on how things get work. Next time I'll do more research and study. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

The htmlentities is here:

`<td>
{{ $sql }}
</td>`.

`$sql` probably is null, undefined or an array. Try debug this before pass to view or, change the line to `<?php dd($sql) ?>` to debug the var. Only strings can be converted by htmlentities and this is what `{{}}` does.

Answer (score 0):

You passed "sqls" instead of "sql" from your Controller to your View. So you should have this instead:

```
<td>
{{ $sqls }}
</td>
```