# [Contact form]How to convert object to string in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm studying contact form script. It works fine but after I add this lines
I'm having this error.

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /home/------/resources/views/mail.blade.php)

> Here is my contact.blade.php

```
@php
$week = array( "日", "月", "火", "水", "木", "金", "土" );
$s_date = date("Y年m月d日 H時i分");
$dayofweek = "(".$week[date("w")].")";
$s2_date = $s_date . $dayofweek;
$k_no_raw = strval("km_".date("Y_md_His_A") ."_". date('w'));

@endphp

<br>
        <input name="sdate" type="hidden" value="{{ $s2_date }}">
        <input name="k_no" type="hidden" value="{{ $k_no_raw }}">
```

I tried to change object to string.
but I still got same error.

> Controller part of this section

```
\Mail::send('mail', array(
    'sdate' => $request->get('sdate'),
    'k_no' => $request->get('k_no'),
),
```

> Here is mail.blade.php

```
{{ $k_no }}
```

Could someone teach me right code please?

> UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you get if you do `{{ dd($k_no) }}` in your mail.blade?

Comment: Thank you for answering me I did dd  here is result    "km_2020_1027_102446_AM_2"

Comment: that seems like a plane string to me. Are you certain it is that piece of the code that breaks it? What happens if you leave `{{ $k_no }}` out of it for a test?

Comment: make sure you not echo object like `{{ $object }}` in blade it cannot be parse you need to give string to print `{{ $string }}` so debug this

Comment: Dear @rob-biermann Thank you again. I see... I still don't get what is cause. I update my question. Could you look at this please?

Comment: Dear @kamlesh-paul Thank you for answering me . Sorry I'm not sure what you said. Could you point out what part of my should I change please?

Comment: as you mentioned `{{ $k_no }}` this is your using .? in blade is this a object .? if yes then it is wrong you cannot `<?php echo $objcet ?>` so

Comment: Thank you everyone. I figure out the problem. this is my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755000/htmlentities-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given  Thank your very much. I appreciate.

Comment: I tried below and it works fine now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755000/htmlentities-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-object-given